# Solving equations with different deriratives.

Tags: integration

I have equation, where secondary derivative is expressed in terms of first derivative. I need to find expression just for x. The first formula top is given. The second and third ones are what I tried, however I am not sure if it is correct. The `z` is just a constant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=dx/dt$:
$$dp/dt=-zp|p|\implies dp/(p|p|)=-zdt\implies ??$$
Use ${\rm sgn}(x)=x/|x|,x\ne0;=0,x=0$